# How to render inside a paragraph template a specific view mode for that paragragh

Tags: theming, paragraphs

You may say that I should just change the display settings but in my use case I need to include 2 view modes inside one template as the mobile and desktop version of the output require very different HTML.

Is there a way to do this or do I require some preprocess function to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

`{{ drupal_entity('paragraph', NUMERIC_ID, VIEWMODE_MACHINE_NAME) }}`

Also see the [cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)  for Twig tweak, it really is a great module for frontend work!

Comment: thank you very much, Do you know how to get the numeric ID of the paragraph?

Comment: If you are using the paragraph.html.twig template, you can use {{ paragraph.id() }} - it's described in the code documentation of that template file.

Answer (score 0):

This question is linked from this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263451/how-to-print-render-nested-paragraph-values-to-twig-template/263497). Since that question is closed, I'll answer here since I recently found something that's working (in case someone else is directed here and needs help).

My setup is like this:

Paragraph field > Paragraph Field > Some Field

I wanted to get the value of 'Some Field'. Here's how I did that:

```
content.field_paragraph.0['#paragraph'].getFields()['field_content_some_field'].getValue()[0]['value']
```

This code goes in the paragraph--some-paragraph-name.html.twig.

Hope this is able to help someone.