# How to print/render nested Paragraph values to twig template?

Tags: theming, entities, paragraphs

I'm trying to figure out how I can render values from nested `Paragraphs`. Basically I have field/values from a `Paragraph` within a `Paragraph` I have tried experimenting and searching for answers but I can't seem display the values from the nested `Paragraphs` to the twig template.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the sample of the code below that I have been working on

```
First Paragraph     
{% for paragraph in node.field_sidebar_area %}

    <h2>{{ paragraph.entity.field_label.value }}</h2>

    <ul>

        {% for block_query in paragraph.entity.field_block_query  %}

            {{ block_query.entity.body.value | raw }}

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

    <ul>
         {% for link in paragraph.entity.field_link_item %}

         <li>{{ link.url }}</li>
         <li>{{ link.title }}</li>

         {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    Second Paragraph
    {% for object in paragraph.node.field_sidebar_content %}

        {{ object.entity.field_label.value }}

    {% endfor }

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What I'm asking for here is trying to print values from nested paragraphs..

Comment: The code you posted isn’t even working though? That looks like Menu twig code which won’t work here. You render paragraphs like normal fields, they have their own twigs and preprocess hooks as well.

Comment: @Kevin the `field_menu` is just a machine name, it's not actually a menu.

Comment: You are using `{{ node.field... }}`  variables, they only work in `node--xxx.hml.twig` templates, not in paragaph templates. Paragraph have their own `paragraph--xxx.html.twig` templates, and you need to access fields in there with `{{ paragraph.field... }}`

Comment: @Hudri I'm using  `{{ node.field }}` on my `page.html.twig`. Currently printing the values / data to my page.html.twig template

Answer (score 4):

I am also curious about the best way to do this. While I'm still trying to figure out what that is, here is what I've done:

I've enabled the Twig Tweak module, and inside the first paragraph template, I pull in the second paragraph with a selected view mode.

```
{{ drupal_entity('paragraph', content.field_sidebar_area[0]['#paragraph'].id(), 'MY_CUSTOM_VIEW_MODE') }}
```

And then in the template for the second paragraph, I can adjust the Twig as I please. Note that the naming convention would be:

```
paragraph--PARAGRAPH-TYPE--MY-CUSTOM-VIEW-MODE.html.twig.
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance how do you fetch or print the paragraphs on the `page.html.twig`

Comment: You should be able to use that same code, but you could replace the 'MY_CUSTOM_VIEW_MODE' with 'default'. Note that this requires Twig Tweak to be enabled.

Comment: An example without Twig Tweak would be great.